# Folder compare tool?

Tags: windows, filesystems

I'm looking for a Windows GUI tool to compare the contents of two folders and show which files are different....

Comment: Have you Googled? What are your requirements?

Comment: I'm not sure why this has 3 close votes already. It's the sort of thing I do often in my role as a system administrator. Incidentally, I prefer WinMerge.

Comment: If you're comparing two **files** I'm sure it will be **those two files** that are different, if any.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: hah, typo on my part... meant to say compare two folders.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use this [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Comment: I have used it and even though it doesn't look amazing it does the job and has a lot of options to display the result, plus it's free and open source.

Answer (score 5):

[KDiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) does a pretty neat job for merging. To add, it also allows [Directory Comparison and Merge](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/dirmerge.html)

Answer (score 4):

Another options is [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) or [P4Merge](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/products/merge.html)

Comment: P4Merge is brilliant, my absolute favourite 3-way merge tool, but unfortunately it only compares individual files. It doesn't do folders, which is what the OP is about.

Answer (score 3):

I check all recommended applications , and find out this one more useful.

[FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/?source=dlp)

That application have compare two folder you easily. If you use this commend in its filter "*" and use = button in under pages you just see each folders, that they are same in other location.

enjoy it

Answer (score 2):

Araxis Merge is by far the most popular and powerful, and the most expensive.
WinMerge is free, but is not very helpful when doing folder compare/merges/syncs.
Beyond Compare is a better option: has all the options (compare/merge/sync,) costs 360$ for 20 licenses.

Comment: Care to provide the source of your claim that Aaxis Merge is "by far the most popular and powerful"? I've never seen anything to suggest it's anything more than just another alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little bit shocked that Total Commanders folder compare ability wasn't mentioned so far.

#### [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)

> Features in Total Commander 8.01 now include
>   - Two file windows side by side
>   - Multiple language and Unicode support
>   - Enhanced search function
>   - Compare files (now with editor) / synchronize directories

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[SourceGear DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) compares files and folders, and is free to use.